# Hidden file visible

Tags: windows, directory, mac

Okay. So on one of my friends computer, which runs Windows 8, I needed to password protect a folder. I did it using command prompt on windows by running:
E:
attrib  +s +h

I then made the batch file to type a password and converted it to a executable file so it couldn't be edited if someone took it from me, or something like that.... It worked. The file was hidden and everything. I tried it on a school PC and it worked. File was hidden and the .exe worked... I got home and put my flash drive in. The .exe file works (with WINE) but it opens winrar and not the file it should. The main problem is that the file that should be hidden is visible.. I'm guessing it would do the same thing on a Mac then, too, right? Can someone tell me how to make it so that it is hidden on a Linux, Windows, AND Mac?

If you can't.... Thanks for reading the long thing anyway..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, what you want to hide from whom, but the *system* and *hidden* attribute in file systems designed for DOS/Windows only means: please don't list/display this file unless the user chooses to. This concept doesn't translate directly to *nix semantics. To provide multiple solutions to users of the NTFS file system, [`ntfs-3g(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html), the NTFS mount program on Linux, offers the mount options `hide_hid_files` and `show_sys_files`, that you can read about in [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html).